# update state when url changes in redux-react

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a `Profile` component that shows user profile. On route change to `user/:userId`, the `userId` query param will be updated in `ownProps` thanks to `react-router-redux` and will then be passed into my presentation component:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  userId: ownProps.params.userId,
  user: store.profile.user //null at first, will be updated later
})
```

At this point, I need to fetch user profile from `userId`. Where should I do this fetching? Currently I am doing it in `componentDidMount`

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchProfile(this.props.userId)  //this will dispatch an action to fetch user details and store in `store.profile.user`
}
```

The downside of this is if user goes from `/users/1` to `/users/2`, `componentDidMount` wont trigger. How should this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to call `this.props.fetchProfile` from your component's `componentDidUpdate` method, with an (optional) additional check to see if the `userId` actually changed. Better yet, you should wrap the call of `fetchProfile` in a separate method, just in case you'd like to skip the call if the `userId` is null, for example.

```
fetchProfile() {
  this.props.userId && this.props.fetchProfile(this.props.userId)
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchProfile()
}

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  prevProps.userId !== this.props.userId && this.fetchProfile()
}
```